# Error Installing 'rhc' Rubygems on Windows

Tags: ruby, windows, rubygems, openshift, openshift-client-tools

I'm trying to install and configure 'OpenShift' on Windows. I installed the necessary tools like: Git, RubyGem 2.x, but when I try to install 'rhc' ruby gem I got this error:

```
C:\>ruby -v
ruby 2.1.6p336 (2015-04-13 revision 50298) [x64-mingw32]
C:\>gem install rhc
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'rhc' (>= 0) in any repositor
C:\>
```

I've been searching this issue through the Internet, but it was unsuccessfully...

When I run the following command: $gem sources, I got this.

```
C:\>gem sources
*** CURRENT SOURCES ***     
C:\>
```

It seems like something is wrong here, but yes, I did what you think. I "added" the source but...

```
C:\>gem source -a http://rubygems.org
[https://rubygems.org][1] is recommended for security over http://rubygems.org

Do you want to add this insecure source? [yn]  y
Error fetching [http://rubygems.org][1]:
        no such name (http://rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)
C:\>
```

What should I do guys? I've been reading so many forums and other webpages, but none of them gave me a solution to that.

Additional information: Windows 7 (x64), Ruby 2.1.6 (actually I had installed Ruby 2.2, but I found in some forums that this issue can fixed just back to and old version of Ruby). *I use a proxy to connect me to Internet.*

---

**Updating info.**

```
C:\>gem install rhc --source http://rubygems.org
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'rhc' (>= 0), here is why:
          Unable to download data from http://rubygems.org/ - no such name (http://rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)

C:\>gem sources -c
*** Removed specs cache ***

C:\>gem sources -u
source cache successfully updated

C:\>gem install rhc --source http://rubygems.org
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'rhc' (>= 0), here is why:
          Unable to download data from http://rubygems.org/ - no such name (http://rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)

C:\>
```

Comment: Downgrade Ruby to 1.9 and it should solve your issues. This is a known issue with the rhc tool on Windows.

Comment: @mbaird Thanks for your answer! 
I'm gonna do this. And I will be back for a feedback !

Comment: @mbaird I tried, but was the same result. I changed to Ruby 1.9, and the problem it's the same.

Comment: Could you try `gem install rhc --source http://rubygems.org`, try doing `gem sources -c` then `gem sources -u`, also provide some information on how you connect to the internet (e.g. through a proxy, an odd dns setup, etc).

Comment: @Azolo ... the result of those commands, they are already in the description. And I use a proxy to connect me to the Internet.

Comment: Ok, it's probably the proxy then. Give me a bit and I'll get the solution for how to connect through a proxy for you if you haven't figured it out by the time I get a chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the important information that you shared in your comments [(you're behind a proxy)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31341229/error-installing-rhc-rubygems-on-windows/31351668#comment50785130_31341229) means that you will have to set some *environment variables* in order to use `rubygems` through the proxy.

In `cmd.exe` use:

```
set http_proxy=http://user:password@proxy_ip:port
```

or in *PowerShell*:

```
$env:http_proxy=http://user:password@proxy_ip:port
```

There was a case where that [format didn't work](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/1068) and a different format had to be used:

```
http_proxy = proxy_ip:port
http_proxy_user = user
http_proxy_pass = password
```

**Domain Users**:

Try without the *Domain* prefix first, unless you know that the default *Domain* isn't set or that your *Domain* isn't the default.

Using a *Domain User Login* and the `domain\user` format, the `\` must be replaced using its [percent-encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) equivalent counterpart: **`%5C`**.

```
http://domain%5Cuser:password@proxy_ip:port
```

Comment: and after this, I must be able to install the rhc rubygem right? ... if so, look this, maybe I'm missing something. `ERROR:  While executing gem ... (URI::InvalidURIError)
    bad URI(is not URI?): http://damin\myuser:mypassword@ipProxy:portProxy`

Comment: You have to replace the the `myuser`, `mypassword`, `ipProxy`, `portProxy` with the corresponding information to connect to your proxy server.

Comment: Yeap, I did it. I replaced it with the correct information, but that was the result, that kind of error.

Comment: err, sorry are you using *domain* authentication? If so can you try it without the *domain* prefixed? If not you will have to use `http://domain%5Cuser:password@proxy_ip:port`

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much for that advise, it works! Thanks for your help fixing this kind of issue.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like [`rubygems.org` was having problems](https://twitter.com/rubygems_status/status/619194799523004417) around the time you posted this question.

However, [it should be fixed now](https://twitter.com/rubygems_status/status/619516810275221504).

Comment: Ok, then I would guess it's a little bit weird. But it's going to take some debugging.